# Azure Storage Account authenticate using Managed Identity and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to authenticate an Azure Storage Account using a user assigned managed identity but, getting the following error:

> unable to authenticate azure storage using user assigned managed identity ...

Earlier, in the Azure portal, I've provided contributor access to the managed identity in the Storage account. All other parameters (AccountURL, container name and managed identity) are correct. I am getting the error in the `await blobClient.UploadAsync`

Please find the code below,

```
public class BlobStorageManager
{
    private BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = null;

    public BlobStorageManager()
    {
        var accountURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountURL"].ToString();
        var containerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContainerName"].ToString();
        var managedIdentity = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ManagedIdentity"].ToString();       

        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(accountURL), new ManagedIdentityCredential(managedIdentity));

        blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadFileToBlobAsync(string fileName, Stream fileData, string contentType)
    {
        try
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

            var blobHttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders()
            {
                ContentType = contentType
            };

            var blobUploadOptions = new BlobUploadOptions()
            {
                HttpHeaders = blobHttpHeaders
            };

            await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileData, blobUploadOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
```

I am using Azure.Identity 1.4.0 and Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.10.0

Am I missing any step? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contributor role does not grant data plane access.
It only gives access to manage the Storage account resource itself.

You need to grant the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the Managed Identity.
This will give it data access.

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried providing the following 3 access(s)
a) Contributor
b) Storage Account Contributor
c) Storage Blob Data Contributor
But, still facing the same issue.

Comment: That's odd. I've made a sample that uses the new blob library here: https://github.com/juunas11/Joonasw.ManagedIdentityDemos. It assigns the Blob Data Contributor role to managed identity on the Storage container level and allows uploads and downloads of blobs.

Comment: @junnas, you were right. I missed assigning the managed identity in my Azure VM. Once this step is done I am able connect. Thank you very much for your response.